# Objective C Path drawing to link buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

Does anyone have any idea on how to make a path drawing to "link" up two buttons like the iphone game Airline Conqueror?

Comment: Could you maybe explain more for those of us who haven't seen Airline Conqueror?

Comment: Are you just asking about drawing a line between two buttons?

Comment: yep it is just like i have two buttons and in order to execute an action i have to draw a line to connect these two buttons to run act as a button pressed on that area.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen Airline Conqueror, but I suppose it might be like the lines that Interface Builder draws when you define button actions.  That's done by drawing into a transparent window at a high level, probably the overlay level (kCGOverlayWindowLevelKey).